# Scrape specific duplicated element from a page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i'm having some issues while scraping this:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa">
```

Before this string i found out that there are already 4 identical ones but with different token values, how can i scrape the 5th out of 6 ones using beautifulsoup?

Unluckily i can't provide examples of the code or the website since i'm working on a private project, before flagging my question as not complete please make some questions, ty!

Comment: use `find_all` (or the `findAll`) method, it returns a list, then simply use an index, also you can provide a smaller html sample with the code for that small sample, just basically write html for only those 6 or whatever input tags and provide code for that html document

Comment: @Matiiss could you please drop a snippet? never used the find_all function

Comment: it is the same as `.find()` except it returns a list of all the found matching tags not just the first one, just use it the same way you use `.find()` and print the result, it should be a list, then simply use indexes

Answer (score 0):

The find_all() method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves all descendants that match your filters and return the result as a list. you can read beautiful soup documentation in this [link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) for more.

To find the 5th element in your code do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aba-token-aba">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aca-token-aca">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="ada-token-ada">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aea-token-aea">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="afa-token-afa">
    '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

element = soup.find_all("input")

print(element[4])
print(element[4]["value"])
```

Result :

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aea-token-aea"/>
aea-token-aea
```

Try always provide a smaller HTML sample with the code as I did above, To avoid flagging your question as not complete

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 5th `<input>` tag in two ways.

- Using `select_one()` - Select the 5th `<input>` tag

  ```
  x = soup.select_one('input:nth-of-type(5)')
  ```
- Using `find_all()` by the attribute `name` - Returns a list of matching `<input>` tags.

  ```
  y = soup.find_all('input', attrs= {'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})[4]
  ```

> If you have only these 6 `<input>` tags in the entire HTML the **Use `select_one()`.**

> If you have other `<input>` tags other than these 6, then you have to specifically select the input tags that you need - So you have to filter the input tags with attribute `name = __RequestVerificationToken`. **Use `find_all()`.**

This code will print the value of the 5th input tag using `select_one()` and `find_all()`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa1">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa2">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa3">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa4">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa5">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa6">
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
# Using select_one()
x = soup.select_one('input:nth-of-type(5)')
print(x)
print(x['value'])

# Using find_all()
y = soup.find_all('input', attrs= {'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})[4]
print(y)
print(y['value'])
```

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa5"/>
aaa-token-aaa5

<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aaa-token-aaa5"/>
aaa-token-aaa5
```

Comment: keep getting this: Exception occured : list index out of range  retrying in  3  seconds...